# Can virus and bacteria move on the surface?

Tags: molecular-biology, bacteriology, virology, infection

Do viruses/bacteria have some motive mechanism? I mean if the virus/bacteria reach some surface by touching, can it move on that surface?

Life example: suppose the cooler is not so clean and has some viruses on his surface. My cup came into contact with the cooler in some little area, so virus migrated to that little area of my cup. Can the virus eventually move to another area of my cup's surface? Or can I be sure that it remained at the point of contact? If yes, is this also true for bacteria?

P.S. obviously parasites can move, but I can't figure out are the viruses and bacteria can..

Comment: What's a silent downvote? Please explain.

Comment: Viruses and bacteria are very very different from one another; asking about them both in one question is asking too many questions. I've marked a duplicate for the virus half of your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I can guess the reason. You did not do a simple search for this question yourself. It is elementary microbiology (also physics). And as @BryanKrause pointed out bacteria and viruses are very different.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Also easily found here. I located the duplicate by searching this site for the two words "virus move". The ask-a-question dialogue pretty clearly suggests askers search the site before asking.

Comment: @BryanKrause Indeed. There is a similar question. Sorry, it is because of my bad English..